# How to securely refresh "last seen" record in user database

Tags: javascript, php, security, zend-framework2

I am trying to design a particular module of a ZF2 application which displays users who are currently online.

### My thoughts:

Have a `lastSeen`column in database. To display the list of users currently online,just search by timestamp (For example: 90 seconds of current time)

If a user is logged in, I plan to have an event listener set up so that, once the controller dispatch is complete, it updates the `lastSeen` field for the current user. When they log out, it will then clear out the `lastSeen` field.

When the user is idle, I plan to use JavaScript to poll the server every 60 seconds or so to ensure that the record keeps getting refreshed.

Three questions:

1. Will this work? (If not, why not?)
2. Can you see any potential security holes?
3. For the JavaScript, is there any need for some kind of csrf-protection? If so, how should I go about handling this?

I'm pretty concerned about security, so I really would like to know if there's anything I'm missing here that could open up security holes.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript refresh is not mandatory : `lastSeen` is a timestamp, so you can calculate a limit beyond which the user will not be considered online.

Comment: True, but I want to keep the list as current as possible. If the lastSeen field is more than, say five minutes old, how can one determine if it's because they're at the page but not active, or if they've left the site? With the JavaScript, at least we'll know if they're still actively browsing the site or not.

Comment: I disagree. :) With JS, you can't tell if the user has originated the request. You don't even know if he is in front of the screen. You know your user is active only when he clicks on a link, hence the name of your variable `lastSeen`